# Mplus Monte Carlo Sim w/Covariates

Tags: logistic-regression, simulation, monte-carlo

I have an Mplus INP file with which I am running a Monte Carlo sim for a latent class analysis. I have the class solution working properly, but I genuinely cannot figure out how to add in covariates to be tested via the Vermunt 3-step method. I can do this with actual data no problem, but something about the syntax, or my lack of understanding the syntax for the covariates in the simulation is keeping me from testing it. Any assistance would be helpful. Here is the simulation INP file:

````
MONTECARLO:
    NAMES = SAS_1_m SAS_2_m SAS_3_m SAS_4_m
       SAS_5_m SAS_6_m SAS_7_m SAS_8_m SAS_9_m SAS_10_m SAS_11_m SAS_12_m SAS_13_m
       SAS_14_m SAS_15_m SAS_16_m SAS_17_m SAS_18_m SAS_19_m SAS_20_m SAS_21_m
       SAS_22_m SAS_23_m SAS_24_m SAS_25_m SAS_26_m SAS_27_m SAS_28_m SAS_29_m
       SAS_30_m SAS_31_m SAS_32_m SAS_33_m;
    
    GENERATE = SAS_1_m-SAS_33_m(5 p);   
    
    CATEGORICAL = SAS_1_m SAS_2_m SAS_3_m SAS_4_m SAS_5_m
       SAS_6_m SAS_7_m SAS_8_m SAS_9_m SAS_10_m SAS_11_m SAS_12_m SAS_13_m SAS_14_m
       SAS_15_m SAS_16_m SAS_17_m SAS_18_m SAS_19_m SAS_20_m SAS_21_m SAS_22_m
       SAS_23_m SAS_24_m SAS_25_m SAS_26_m SAS_27_m SAS_28_m SAS_29_m SAS_30_m
       SAS_31_m SAS_32_m SAS_33_m;
    
    NOBSERVATIONS = 357;
    NREPS = 10;
    SEED = 1024;
    GENCLASSES = c(3);
    CLASSES = c(3);

ANALYSIS:
    TYPE = MIXTURE;
    ESTIMATOR = MLR;
    PROCESSORS = 12;

MODEL POPULATION:

     %OVERALL%

     [ c#1*-0.63455 ];
     [ c#2*-0.30947 ];

     %C#1%

     [ sas_1_m$1*-1.73598 ];
 [ sas_1_m$2*-0.98372 ];
     [ sas_1_m$3*-0.47429 ];
 [ sas_1_m$4*0.37448 ];
     [ sas_1_m$5*2.21343 ];
 [ sas_2_m$1*-4.35269 ];
     [ sas_2_m$2*-2.34065 ];
 [ sas_2_m$3*-1.32800 ];
     [ sas_2_m$4*0.12210 ];
 [ sas_2_m$5*1.48487 ];
     [ sas_3_m$1*-1.25882 ];
 [ sas_3_m$2*-0.69381 ];
     [ sas_3_m$3*-0.16782 ];
 [ sas_3_m$4*0.81065 ];
     [ sas_3_m$5*1.96261 ];
 [ sas_4_m$1*-1.63998 ];
     [ sas_4_m$2*-0.52545 ];
 [ sas_4_m$3*0.32358 ];
     [ sas_4_m$4*1.25473 ];
 [ sas_4_m$5*2.36165 ];
     [ sas_5_m$1*-2.22164 ];
 [ sas_5_m$2*-1.47869 ];
     [ sas_5_m$3*-1.10403 ];
 [ sas_5_m$4*-0.52180 ];
     [ sas_5_m$5*1.05413 ];
 [ sas_6_m$1*-5 ];
     [ sas_6_m$2*-4.34334 ];
 [ sas_6_m$3*-1.64909 ];
     [ sas_6_m$4*-0.06871 ];
 [ sas_6_m$5*1.57514 ];
     [ sas_7_m$1*-5 ];
 [ sas_7_m$2*-4.37355 ];
     [ sas_7_m$3*-1.84722 ];
 [ sas_7_m$4*-0.31639 ];
     [ sas_7_m$5*1.58674 ];
 [ sas_8_m$1*-4.38604 ];
     [ sas_8_m$2*-2.35979 ];
 [ sas_8_m$3*-0.91139 ];
     [ sas_8_m$4*0.07630 ];
 [ sas_8_m$5*1.96947 ];
     [ sas_9_m$1*-3.25329 ];
 [ sas_9_m$2*-1.82558 ];
     [ sas_9_m$3*-0.96951 ];
 [ sas_9_m$4*0.09085 ];
     [ sas_9_m$5*1.76262 ];
 [ sas_10_m$1*-1.49477 ];
     [ sas_10_m$2*-0.18200 ];
 [ sas_10_m$3*0.92749 ];
     [ sas_10_m$4*1.85370 ];
 [ sas_10_m$5*3.67957 ];
     [ sas_11_m$1*-2.51323 ];
 [ sas_11_m$2*-0.69108 ];
     [ sas_11_m$3*0.08109 ];
 [ sas_11_m$4*0.99502 ];
     [ sas_11_m$5*2.21455 ];
 [ sas_12_m$1*-3.25993 ];
     [ sas_12_m$2*-0.99683 ];
 [ sas_12_m$3*0.07864 ];
     [ sas_12_m$4*1.32970 ];
 [ sas_12_m$5*3.26140 ];
     [ sas_13_m$1*-1.32807 ];
 [ sas_13_m$2*0.01867 ];
     [ sas_13_m$3*0.59140 ];
 [ sas_13_m$4*1.75301 ];
     [ sas_13_m$5*3.67957 ];
 [ sas_14_m$1*-1.95504 ];
     [ sas_14_m$2*-1.18698 ];
 [ sas_14_m$3*-0.52584 ];
     [ sas_14_m$4*0.52684 ];
 [ sas_14_m$5*1.74563 ];
     [ sas_15_m$1*-1.66979 ];
 [ sas_15_m$2*-0.49259 ];
     [ sas_15_m$3*0.37764 ];
 [ sas_15_m$4*1.05396 ];
     [ sas_15_m$5*2.52917 ];
 [ sas_16_m$1*-2.72752 ];
     [ sas_16_m$2*-0.63300 ];
 [ sas_16_m$3*0.12308 ];
     [ sas_16_m$4*0.99087 ];
 [ sas_16_m$5*2.72469 ];
     [ sas_17_m$1*-2.93105 ];
 [ sas_17_m$2*-0.91382 ];
     [ sas_17_m$3*-0.15691 ];
 [ sas_17_m$4*1.05659 ];
     [ sas_17_m$5*2.53597 ];
 [ sas_18_m$1*-2.69956 ];
     [ sas_18_m$2*-0.63740 ];
 [ sas_18_m$3*0.17908 ];
     [ sas_18_m$4*1.48540 ];
 [ sas_18_m$5*3.26140 ];
     [ sas_19_m$1*-3.66286 ];
 [ sas_19_m$2*-2.51967 ];
     [ sas_19_m$3*-2.07173 ];
 [ sas_19_m$4*-1.17405 ];
     [ sas_19_m$5*0.21865 ];
 [ sas_20_m$1*-2.93640 ];
     [ sas_20_m$2*-0.97818 ];
 [ sas_20_m$3*-0.26388 ];
     [ sas_20_m$4*0.81261 ];
 [ sas_20_m$5*2.72475 ];
     [ sas_21_m$1*-0.75001 ];
 [ sas_21_m$2*0.47996 ];
     [ sas_21_m$3*1.11663 ];
 [ sas_21_m$4*2.21443 ];
     [ sas_21_m$5*3.26140 ];
 [ sas_22_m$1*-0.85692 ];
     [ sas_22_m$2*0.37930 ];
 [ sas_22_m$3*0.75093 ];
     [ sas_22_m$4*1.40577 ];
 [ sas_22_m$5*3.26140 ];
     [ sas_23_m$1*-0.42638 ];
 [ sas_23_m$2*0.69550 ];
     [ sas_23_m$3*1.05400 ];
 [ sas_23_m$4*1.85428 ];
     [ sas_23_m$5*2.96086 ];
 [ sas_24_m$1*-2.33485 ];
     [ sas_24_m$2*-0.63704 ];
 [ sas_24_m$3*0.02749 ];
     [ sas_24_m$4*0.86847 ];
 [ sas_24_m$5*2.21455 ];
     [ sas_25_m$1*-3.64722 ];
 [ sas_25_m$2*-1.75579 ];
     [ sas_25_m$3*-1.18635 ];
 [ sas_25_m$4*-0.26976 ];
     [ sas_25_m$5*0.75393 ];
 [ sas_26_m$1*-0.27932 ];
     [ sas_26_m$2*0.86764 ];
 [ sas_26_m$3*1.25434 ];
     [ sas_26_m$4*2.72469 ];
 [ sas_26_m$5*4.38525 ];
     [ sas_27_m$1*-2.53032 ];
 [ sas_27_m$2*-1.40449 ];
     [ sas_27_m$3*-0.74619 ];
 [ sas_27_m$4*0.27695 ];
     [ sas_27_m$5*1.66155 ];
 [ sas_28_m$1*-2.06953 ];
     [ sas_28_m$2*-0.92212 ];
 [ sas_28_m$3*-0.74382 ];
     [ sas_28_m$4*-0.31928 ];
 [ sas_28_m$5*0.86726 ];
     [ sas_29_m$1*-3.67957 ];
 [ sas_29_m$2*-3.25801 ];
     [ sas_29_m$3*-3.25000 ];
 [ sas_29_m$4*-1.64941 ];
     [ sas_29_m$5*0.08883 ];
 [ sas_30_m$1*-5 ];
     [ sas_30_m$2*-3.70468 ];
 [ sas_30_m$3*-2.08796 ];
     [ sas_30_m$4*-0.28361 ];
 [ sas_30_m$5*1.18707 ];
     [ sas_31_m$1*-5 ];
 [ sas_31_m$2*-3.26399 ];
     [ sas_31_m$3*-1.57871 ];
 [ sas_31_m$4*0.11316 ];
     [ sas_31_m$5*1.48462 ];
 [ sas_32_m$1*-4.36859 ];
     [ sas_32_m$2*-4.36000 ];
 [ sas_32_m$3*-2.33285 ];
     [ sas_32_m$4*-0.74958 ];
 [ sas_32_m$5*0.70847 ];
     [ sas_33_m$1*-2.08508 ];
 [ sas_33_m$2*-0.69719 ];
     [ sas_33_m$3*0.07293 ];
 [ sas_33_m$4*0.99004 ];
     [ sas_33_m$5*2.52917 ];

     %C#2%

     [ sas_1_m$1*-1.48792 ];
 [ sas_1_m$2*0.48002 ];
     [ sas_1_m$3*1.24841 ];
 [ sas_1_m$4*3.07054 ];
     [ sas_1_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_2_m$1*-2.57123 ];
     [ sas_2_m$2*-0.68398 ];
 [ sas_2_m$3*0.27032 ];
     [ sas_2_m$4*1.80320 ];
 [ sas_2_m$5*4.01235 ];
     [ sas_3_m$1*-1.48529 ];
 [ sas_3_m$2*0.48388 ];
     [ sas_3_m$3*1.24906 ];
 [ sas_3_m$4*3.30235 ];
     [ sas_3_m$5*4.01667 ];
 [ sas_4_m$1*-1.48639 ];
     [ sas_4_m$2*0.23451 ];
 [ sas_4_m$3*1.06183 ];
     [ sas_4_m$4*3.08278 ];
 [ sas_4_m$5*4.71379 ];
     [ sas_5_m$1*-2.32699 ];
 [ sas_5_m$2*-0.75911 ];
     [ sas_5_m$3*0.53492 ];
 [ sas_5_m$4*2.47390 ];
     [ sas_5_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_6_m$1*-4.71379 ];
     [ sas_6_m$2*-2.22440 ];
 [ sas_6_m$3*-0.75283 ];
     [ sas_6_m$4*1.10923 ];
 [ sas_6_m$5*4.71510 ];
     [ sas_7_m$1*-3.60501 ];
 [ sas_7_m$2*-2.24152 ];
     [ sas_7_m$3*-0.72730 ];
 [ sas_7_m$4*1.20788 ];
     [ sas_7_m$5*4.58843 ];
 [ sas_8_m$1*-4.71379 ];
     [ sas_8_m$2*-2.34454 ];
 [ sas_8_m$3*-0.80286 ];
     [ sas_8_m$4*0.73415 ];
 [ sas_8_m$5*4.02012 ];
     [ sas_9_m$1*-3.59706 ];
 [ sas_9_m$2*-2.05633 ];
     [ sas_9_m$3*-0.34260 ];
 [ sas_9_m$4*1.06515 ];
     [ sas_9_m$5*4.02345 ];
 [ sas_10_m$1*-1.41194 ];
     [ sas_10_m$2*0.27182 ];
 [ sas_10_m$3*1.41963 ];
     [ sas_10_m$4*3.59923 ];
 [ sas_10_m$5*4.71379 ];
     [ sas_11_m$1*-2.22552 ];
 [ sas_11_m$2*0.12657 ];
     [ sas_11_m$3*1.79774 ];
 [ sas_11_m$4*4 ];
     [ sas_11_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_12_m$1*-3.31467 ];
     [ sas_12_m$2*-0.26281 ];
 [ sas_12_m$3*1.15668 ];
     [ sas_12_m$4*4.71374 ];
 [ sas_12_m$5*5 ];
     [ sas_13_m$1*-1.80707 ];
 [ sas_13_m$2*0.15910 ];
     [ sas_13_m$3*1.41989 ];
 [ sas_13_m$4*4.71374 ];
     [ sas_13_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_14_m$1*-5 ];
     [ sas_14_m$2*-0.71861 ];
 [ sas_14_m$3*0.53178 ];
     [ sas_14_m$4*2.23723 ];
 [ sas_14_m$5*3.62110 ];
     [ sas_15_m$1*-5 ];
 [ sas_15_m$2*-0.25875 ];
     [ sas_15_m$3*1.25662 ];
 [ sas_15_m$4*4.01756 ];
     [ sas_15_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_16_m$1*-3.29778 ];
     [ sas_16_m$2*-0.20076 ];
 [ sas_16_m$3*1.53772 ];
     [ sas_16_m$4*4 ];
 [ sas_16_m$5*5 ];
     [ sas_17_m$1*-4.00691 ];
 [ sas_17_m$2*-0.30508 ];
     [ sas_17_m$3*1.16528 ];
 [ sas_17_m$4*4.01374 ];
     [ sas_17_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_18_m$1*-2.94591 ];
     [ sas_18_m$2*-0.34296 ];
 [ sas_18_m$3*1.01708 ];
     [ sas_18_m$4*2.71375 ];
 [ sas_18_m$5*5 ];
     [ sas_19_m$1*-4.70019 ];
 [ sas_19_m$2*-1.65838 ];
     [ sas_19_m$3*-0.45054 ];
 [ sas_19_m$4*0.75779 ];
     [ sas_19_m$5*2.90202 ];
 [ sas_20_m$1*-4.72801 ];
     [ sas_20_m$2*-0.76932 ];
 [ sas_20_m$3*0.40964 ];
     [ sas_20_m$4*2.03358 ];
 [ sas_20_m$5*4.71380 ];
     [ sas_21_m$1*-1.27076 ];
 [ sas_21_m$2*0.40722 ];
     [ sas_21_m$3*1.87294 ];
 [ sas_21_m$4*3.30063 ];
     [ sas_21_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_22_m$1*-1.22652 ];
     [ sas_22_m$2*0.44420 ];
 [ sas_22_m$3*2.03748 ];
     [ sas_22_m$4*4 ];
 [ sas_22_m$5*5 ];
     [ sas_23_m$1*-1.12168 ];
 [ sas_23_m$2*0.63414 ];
     [ sas_23_m$3*1.79682 ];
 [ sas_23_m$4*4.71379 ];
     [ sas_23_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_24_m$1*-2.02617 ];
     [ sas_24_m$2*-0.01063 ];
 [ sas_24_m$3*1.01832 ];
     [ sas_24_m$4*3.07279 ];
 [ sas_24_m$5*5 ];
     [ sas_25_m$1*-2.56284 ];
 [ sas_25_m$2*-0.68792 ];
     [ sas_25_m$3*-0.09441 ];
 [ sas_25_m$4*1.16145 ];
     [ sas_25_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_26_m$1*-0.97731 ];
     [ sas_26_m$2*0.92356 ];
 [ sas_26_m$3*1.66025 ];
     [ sas_26_m$4*3.30022 ];
 [ sas_26_m$5*5 ];
     [ sas_27_m$1*-2.87227 ];
 [ sas_27_m$2*-1.36927 ];
     [ sas_27_m$3*-0.41583 ];
 [ sas_27_m$4*1.31394 ];
     [ sas_27_m$5*4.71379 ];
 [ sas_28_m$1*-2.86886 ];
     [ sas_28_m$2*-0.55973 ];
 [ sas_28_m$3*0.45508 ];
     [ sas_28_m$4*1.30739 ];
 [ sas_28_m$5*2.58195 ];
     [ sas_29_m$1*-4.71356 ];
 [ sas_29_m$2*-1.86912 ];
     [ sas_29_m$3*-0.79399 ];
 [ sas_29_m$4*0.88484 ];
     [ sas_29_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_30_m$1*-3.58180 ];
     [ sas_30_m$2*-1.42530 ];
 [ sas_30_m$3*-0.53289 ];
     [ sas_30_m$4*1.47986 ];
 [ sas_30_m$5*4.71187 ];
     [ sas_31_m$1*-3.06791 ];
 [ sas_31_m$2*-0.55619 ];
     [ sas_31_m$3*0.84495 ];
 [ sas_31_m$4*2.57515 ];
     [ sas_31_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_32_m$1*-3.60235 ];
     [ sas_32_m$2*-1.01197 ];
 [ sas_32_m$3*0.05492 ];
     [ sas_32_m$4*1.31073 ];
 [ sas_32_m$5*4.59689 ];
     [ sas_33_m$1*-1.67455 ];
 [ sas_33_m$2*0.41037 ];
     [ sas_33_m$3*1.80231 ];
 [ sas_33_m$4*2.87946 ];
     [ sas_33_m$5*5 ];

     %C#3%

     [ sas_1_m$1*0.46409 ];
 [ sas_1_m$2*1.64177 ];
     [ sas_1_m$3*2.09247 ];
 [ sas_1_m$4*3.40968 ];
     [ sas_1_m$5*5.03383 ];
 [ sas_2_m$1*-0.75574 ];
     [ sas_2_m$2*0.14404 ];
 [ sas_2_m$3*0.52178 ];
     [ sas_2_m$4*1.78952 ];
 [ sas_2_m$5*3.62110 ];
     [ sas_3_m$1*0.19973 ];
 [ sas_3_m$2*1.22036 ];
     [ sas_3_m$3*1.63987 ];
 [ sas_3_m$4*3.20036 ];
     [ sas_3_m$5*3.91379 ];
 [ sas_4_m$1*0.46262 ];
     [ sas_4_m$2*1.36165 ];
 [ sas_4_m$3*1.89741 ];
     [ sas_4_m$4*3.03337 ];
 [ sas_4_m$5*5.02559 ];
     [ sas_5_m$1*-0.78377 ];
 [ sas_5_m$2*0.16798 ];
     [ sas_5_m$3*0.77232 ];
 [ sas_5_m$4*2.06402 ];
     [ sas_5_m$5*4.32578 ];
 [ sas_6_m$1*-2.77445 ];
     [ sas_6_m$2*-1.33296 ];
 [ sas_6_m$3*-0.15035 ];
     [ sas_6_m$4*1.32909 ];
 [ sas_6_m$5*3.89135 ];
     [ sas_7_m$1*-2.37667 ];
 [ sas_7_m$2*-1.13852 ];
     [ sas_7_m$3*-0.13969 ];
 [ sas_7_m$4*1.77990 ];
     [ sas_7_m$5*3.89141 ];
 [ sas_8_m$1*-1.89658 ];
     [ sas_8_m$2*-0.60465 ];
 [ sas_8_m$3*0.19022 ];
     [ sas_8_m$4*1.66194 ];
 [ sas_8_m$5*3.18896 ];
     [ sas_9_m$1*-1.33320 ];
 [ sas_9_m$2*-0.22714 ];
     [ sas_9_m$3*0.40542 ];
 [ sas_9_m$4*1.48152 ];
     [ sas_9_m$5*2.76016 ];
 [ sas_10_m$1*1.03440 ];
     [ sas_10_m$2*2.76933 ];
 [ sas_10_m$3*3.89100 ];
     [ sas_10_m$4*4.32552 ];
 [ sas_10_m$5*5 ];
     [ sas_11_m$1*0.54309 ];
 [ sas_11_m$2*1.77654 ];
     [ sas_11_m$3*2.89496 ];
 [ sas_11_m$4*4.29271 ];
     [ sas_11_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_12_m$1*0.14161 ];
     [ sas_12_m$2*1.45252 ];
 [ sas_12_m$3*2.65616 ];
     [ sas_12_m$4*5.02564 ];
 [ sas_12_m$5*6 ];
     [ sas_13_m$1*1.40705 ];
 [ sas_13_m$2*2.90211 ];
     [ sas_13_m$3*3.58157 ];
 [ sas_13_m$4*5.02494 ];
     [ sas_13_m$5*6 ];
 [ sas_14_m$1*-0.20191 ];
     [ sas_14_m$2*0.60531 ];
 [ sas_14_m$3*1.28162 ];
     [ sas_14_m$4*2.66388 ];
 [ sas_14_m$5*4.32874 ];
     [ sas_15_m$1*0.57630 ];
 [ sas_15_m$2*1.83538 ];
     [ sas_15_m$3*2.65858 ];
 [ sas_15_m$4*3.19891 ];
     [ sas_15_m$5*5.02564 ];
 [ sas_16_m$1*0.51671 ];
     [ sas_16_m$2*2.29251 ];
 [ sas_16_m$3*3.04325 ];
     [ sas_16_m$4*5.02561 ];
 [ sas_16_m$5*15 ];
     [ sas_17_m$1*0.32225 ];
 [ sas_17_m$2*1.32242 ];
     [ sas_17_m$3*2.61457 ];
 [ sas_17_m$4*3.38082 ];
     [ sas_17_m$5*4.98839 ];
 [ sas_18_m$1*0.25269 ];
     [ sas_18_m$2*1.58558 ];
 [ sas_18_m$3*2.36802 ];
     [ sas_18_m$4*4.32263 ];
 [ sas_18_m$5*5 ];
     [ sas_19_m$1*-1.04245 ];
 [ sas_19_m$2*-0.58168 ];
     [ sas_19_m$3*-0.19645 ];
 [ sas_19_m$4*0.41286 ];
     [ sas_19_m$5*1.37464 ];
 [ sas_20_m$1*-1.33543 ];
     [ sas_20_m$2*-0.06397 ];
 [ sas_20_m$3*0.69095 ];
     [ sas_20_m$4*2.14859 ];
 [ sas_20_m$5*3.61938 ];
     [ sas_21_m$1*1.41386 ];
 [ sas_21_m$2*2.46611 ];
     [ sas_21_m$3*3.20450 ];
 [ sas_21_m$4*3.61925 ];
     [ sas_21_m$5*5.02564 ];
 [ sas_22_m$1*1.41360 ];
     [ sas_22_m$2*2.55621 ];
 [ sas_22_m$3*3.20462 ];
     [ sas_22_m$4*5.02564 ];
 [ sas_22_m$5*5.12564 ];
     [ sas_23_m$1*1.73416 ];
 [ sas_23_m$2*2.66468 ];
     [ sas_23_m$3*3.38958 ];
 [ sas_23_m$4*3.91381 ];
     [ sas_23_m$5*5 ];
 [ sas_24_m$1*0.39907 ];
     [ sas_24_m$2*1.28111 ];
 [ sas_24_m$3*2.14351 ];
     [ sas_24_m$4*2.89834 ];
 [ sas_24_m$5*4.32590 ];
     [ sas_25_m$1*-0.38974 ];
 [ sas_25_m$2*0.07240 ];
     [ sas_25_m$3*0.33653 ];
 [ sas_25_m$4*1.25088 ];
     [ sas_25_m$5*2.66212 ];
 [ sas_26_m$1*2.29634 ];
     [ sas_26_m$2*3.03961 ];
 [ sas_26_m$3*3.20059 ];
     [ sas_26_m$4*4 ];
 [ sas_26_m$5*5 ];
     [ sas_27_m$1*-1.29382 ];
 [ sas_27_m$2*-0.69046 ];
     [ sas_27_m$3*-0.06477 ];
 [ sas_27_m$4*1.03628 ];
     [ sas_27_m$5*2.77033 ];
 [ sas_28_m$1*-0.25674 ];
     [ sas_28_m$2*0.48836 ];
 [ sas_28_m$3*0.99855 ];
     [ sas_28_m$4*1.58861 ];
 [ sas_28_m$5*2.37409 ];
     [ sas_29_m$1*-1.63526 ];
 [ sas_29_m$2*-0.87924 ];
     [ sas_29_m$3*-0.52476 ];
 [ sas_29_m$4*0.75582 ];
     [ sas_29_m$5*2.45010 ];
 [ sas_30_m$1*-0.94317 ];
     [ sas_30_m$2*0.06823 ];
 [ sas_30_m$3*0.58530 ];
     [ sas_30_m$4*1.74490 ];
 [ sas_30_m$5*3.03934 ];
     [ sas_31_m$1*-0.72529 ];
 [ sas_31_m$2*0.57331 ];
     [ sas_31_m$3*1.37881 ];
 [ sas_31_m$4*1.91346 ];
     [ sas_31_m$5*3.39184 ];
 [ sas_32_m$1*-1.63530 ];
     [ sas_32_m$2*-0.66657 ];
 [ sas_32_m$3*-0.17270 ];
     [ sas_32_m$4*0.55400 ];
 [ sas_32_m$5*1.63204 ];
     [ sas_33_m$1*0.41377 ];
 [ sas_33_m$2*1.96157 ];
     [ sas_33_m$3*2.47220 ];
 [ sas_33_m$4*3.61801 ];
     [ sas_33_m$5*5.02563 ];


MODEL:

     %OVERALL%

     [ c#1*-0.63455 ];
     [ c#2*-0.30947 ];

     %C#1%

     [ sas_1_m$1*-1.73598 ];
 [ sas_1_m$2*-0.98372 ];
     [ sas_1_m$3*-0.47429 ];
 [ sas_1_m$4*0.37448 ];
     [ sas_1_m$5*2.21343 ];
 [ sas_2_m$1*-4.35269 ];
     [ sas_2_m$2*-2.34065 ];
 [ sas_2_m$3*-1.32800 ];
     [ sas_2_m$4*0.12210 ];
 [ sas_2_m$5*1.48487 ];
     [ sas_3_m$1*-1.25882 ];
 [ sas_3_m$2*-0.69381 ];
     [ sas_3_m$3*-0.16782 ];
 [ sas_3_m$4*0.81065 ];
     [ sas_3_m$5*1.96261 ];
 [ sas_4_m$1*-1.63998 ];
     [ sas_4_m$2*-0.52545 ];
 [ sas_4_m$3*0.32358 ];
     [ sas_4_m$4*1.25473 ];
 [ sas_4_m$5*2.36165 ];
     [ sas_5_m$1*-2.22164 ];
 [ sas_5_m$2*-1.47869 ];
     [ sas_5_m$3*-1.10403 ];
 [ sas_5_m$4*-0.52180 ];
     [ sas_5_m$5*1.05413 ];
 [ sas_6_m$1*-15 ];
     [ sas_6_m$2*-4.34334 ];
 [ sas_6_m$3*-1.64909 ];
     [ sas_6_m$4*-0.06871 ];
 [ sas_6_m$5*1.57514 ];
     [ sas_7_m$1*-15 ];
 [ sas_7_m$2*-4.37355 ];
     [ sas_7_m$3*-1.84722 ];
 [ sas_7_m$4*-0.31639 ];
     [ sas_7_m$5*1.58674 ];
 [ sas_8_m$1*-4.38604 ];
     [ sas_8_m$2*-2.35979 ];
 [ sas_8_m$3*-0.91139 ];
     [ sas_8_m$4*0.07630 ];
 [ sas_8_m$5*1.96947 ];
     [ sas_9_m$1*-3.25329 ];
 [ sas_9_m$2*-1.82558 ];
     [ sas_9_m$3*-0.96951 ];
 [ sas_9_m$4*0.09085 ];
     [ sas_9_m$5*1.76262 ];
 [ sas_10_m$1*-1.49477 ];
     [ sas_10_m$2*-0.18200 ];
 [ sas_10_m$3*0.92749 ];
     [ sas_10_m$4*1.85370 ];
 [ sas_10_m$5*3.67957 ];
     [ sas_11_m$1*-2.51323 ];
 [ sas_11_m$2*-0.69108 ];
     [ sas_11_m$3*0.08109 ];
 [ sas_11_m$4*0.99502 ];
     [ sas_11_m$5*2.21455 ];
 [ sas_12_m$1*-3.25993 ];
     [ sas_12_m$2*-0.99683 ];
 [ sas_12_m$3*0.07864 ];
     [ sas_12_m$4*1.32970 ];
 [ sas_12_m$5*3.26140 ];
     [ sas_13_m$1*-1.32807 ];
 [ sas_13_m$2*0.01867 ];
     [ sas_13_m$3*0.59140 ];
 [ sas_13_m$4*1.75301 ];
     [ sas_13_m$5*3.67957 ];
 [ sas_14_m$1*-1.95504 ];
     [ sas_14_m$2*-1.18698 ];
 [ sas_14_m$3*-0.52584 ];
     [ sas_14_m$4*0.52684 ];
 [ sas_14_m$5*1.74563 ];
     [ sas_15_m$1*-1.66979 ];
 [ sas_15_m$2*-0.49259 ];
     [ sas_15_m$3*0.37764 ];
 [ sas_15_m$4*1.05396 ];
     [ sas_15_m$5*2.52917 ];
 [ sas_16_m$1*-2.72752 ];
     [ sas_16_m$2*-0.63300 ];
 [ sas_16_m$3*0.12308 ];
     [ sas_16_m$4*0.99087 ];
 [ sas_16_m$5*2.72469 ];
     [ sas_17_m$1*-2.93105 ];
 [ sas_17_m$2*-0.91382 ];
     [ sas_17_m$3*-0.15691 ];
 [ sas_17_m$4*1.05659 ];
     [ sas_17_m$5*2.53597 ];
 [ sas_18_m$1*-2.69956 ];
     [ sas_18_m$2*-0.63740 ];
 [ sas_18_m$3*0.17908 ];
     [ sas_18_m$4*1.48540 ];
 [ sas_18_m$5*3.26140 ];
     [ sas_19_m$1*-3.66286 ];
 [ sas_19_m$2*-2.51967 ];
     [ sas_19_m$3*-2.07173 ];
 [ sas_19_m$4*-1.17405 ];
     [ sas_19_m$5*0.21865 ];
 [ sas_20_m$1*-2.93640 ];
     [ sas_20_m$2*-0.97818 ];
 [ sas_20_m$3*-0.26388 ];
     [ sas_20_m$4*0.81261 ];
 [ sas_20_m$5*2.72475 ];
     [ sas_21_m$1*-0.75001 ];
 [ sas_21_m$2*0.47996 ];
     [ sas_21_m$3*1.11663 ];
 [ sas_21_m$4*2.21443 ];
     [ sas_21_m$5*3.26140 ];
 [ sas_22_m$1*-0.85692 ];
     [ sas_22_m$2*0.37930 ];
 [ sas_22_m$3*0.75093 ];
     [ sas_22_m$4*1.40577 ];
 [ sas_22_m$5*3.26140 ];
     [ sas_23_m$1*-0.42638 ];
 [ sas_23_m$2*0.69550 ];
     [ sas_23_m$3*1.05400 ];
 [ sas_23_m$4*1.85428 ];
     [ sas_23_m$5*2.96086 ];
 [ sas_24_m$1*-2.33485 ];
     [ sas_24_m$2*-0.63704 ];
 [ sas_24_m$3*0.02749 ];
     [ sas_24_m$4*0.86847 ];
 [ sas_24_m$5*2.21455 ];
     [ sas_25_m$1*-3.64722 ];
 [ sas_25_m$2*-1.75579 ];
     [ sas_25_m$3*-1.18635 ];
 [ sas_25_m$4*-0.26976 ];
     [ sas_25_m$5*0.75393 ];
 [ sas_26_m$1*-0.27932 ];
     [ sas_26_m$2*0.86764 ];
 [ sas_26_m$3*1.25434 ];
     [ sas_26_m$4*2.72469 ];
 [ sas_26_m$5*4.38525 ];
     [ sas_27_m$1*-2.53032 ];
 [ sas_27_m$2*-1.40449 ];
     [ sas_27_m$3*-0.74619 ];
 [ sas_27_m$4*0.27695 ];
     [ sas_27_m$5*1.66155 ];
 [ sas_28_m$1*-2.06953 ];
     [ sas_28_m$2*-0.92212 ];
 [ sas_28_m$3*-0.74382 ];
     [ sas_28_m$4*-0.31928 ];
 [ sas_28_m$5*0.86726 ];
     [ sas_29_m$1*-3.67957 ];
 [ sas_29_m$2*-3.25801 ];
     [ sas_29_m$3*-3.25000 ];
 [ sas_29_m$4*-1.64941 ];
     [ sas_29_m$5*0.08883 ];
 [ sas_30_m$1*-5 ];
     [ sas_30_m$2*-3.70468 ];
 [ sas_30_m$3*-2.08796 ];
     [ sas_30_m$4*-0.28361 ];
 [ sas_30_m$5*1.18707 ];
     [ sas_31_m$1*-5 ];
 [ sas_31_m$2*-3.26399 ];
     [ sas_31_m$3*-1.57871 ];
 [ sas_31_m$4*0.11316 ];
     [ sas_31_m$5*1.48462 ];
 [ sas_32_m$1*-4.36859 ];
     [ sas_32_m$2*-4.36000 ];
 [ sas_32_m$3*-2.33285 ];
     [ sas_32_m$4*-0.74958 ];
 [ sas_32_m$5*0.70847 ];
     [ sas_33_m$1*-2.08508 ];
 [ sas_33_m$2*-0.69719 ];
     [ sas_33_m$3*0.07293 ];
 [ sas_33_m$4*0.99004 ];
     [ sas_33_m$5*2.52917 ];
*** AND SO ON THROUGH THE MODEL, HAD TO REMOVE FOR CHARACTER LIMITS ON HERE *** 

output:
    tech8 tech9 sampstat;
```
````